# Magento Mage::registry('current_product') not working in Models

Tags: magento, model

I have a custom module. In the Model area of my Custom Module Im trying to retrieve the SKU of a current product to be used in a Public Function.

I tested the current code but Im receiving NULL value in frontend.

```
public function sku(){
        $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct();
        $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('SKU')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $product)
                ->getFirstItem();
        $SKU_id = $model->getSKU();
        var_dump($SKU_id);
}
```

I tried to use the following code too but with the same result:

```
public function sku(){
        $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
        $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('SKU')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $product)
                ->getFirstItem();
        $SKU_id = $model->getSKU();
        var_dump($SKU_id);
}
```

I checked on the internet and it seems mage:registry('current_product') could be retrieved in blocks and controllers but not in models. On the other hand mage:registry('current_product') is a global variable. I dont know what to do to retrieve an attribute of a current product in a magento model.

thanks in advance.

UPDATE------------------------------------------------------------------------

as an example with magento core code, if I want to retrieve the ('current_product')sku inside Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Tax/Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation.html . that its possible with the information available on that file?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where do you call this? If magento didn't register such value at this time you certainly can't get it. Mage::registry is available from any part of magento.

Comment: UPDATED question with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are speaking about Tax Calculation most probably you need products from your quote (cart). Try this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems()
```

If not - let us know which product do you want to receive? Be more specific.

**upd.1**

I can access to product via Mage::registry('current_product'). I tried that from catalog/product/view page:

[image]

Here is product object:

[image]

Comment: in tax calculation the $price is retrieve for a particular product and used in eg: public function calcTaxAmount($price....), probably Im confused but if in tax calculation the price of the current product is retrieve,  why not the sku using the same logic?. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on where it's called from.  current_product is injected into the registry from Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product::initProduct().  So if your code is called either before that method or on a request that doesn't call that (only product pages seem to) then the product will not be stored in that registry entry.

So in order to get the current product you will need to load it via the product helper noted above or directly inject the product object into the method.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kevin Schroeder. You should be sure that some previous code has set a current product or that the helper is returning some actual product.

In your code examples above I think you need to pass an integer id for the 'entity_id' so:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $product->getId())
```

and I think you should select `'sku'` instead of `'SKU'` so:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
```

These kinds of typing errors catch me out all the time.

Did you try $product->getData('sku') directly? Sometimes the sku attribute is loaded but it depends on what has happened before and/or on various settings. As Kevin says you should find out why/when/if there is not a current product when your code runs and maybe put in some conditionals to trap that case.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, this depends where you are trying to reach the product in the registry. I suppose you are trying all of this on a "Product View Page" and if you are trying to get the product before it is registered, you can use this in your Model:

`//Product ID is available from the Request object.
$productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$sku = $product->getSku();`

Comment: thanks for you answer, updated information in question. brgds